# Outbound Channel Adapter without spring integration

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-integration

Is it possible to implement a JDBC Outbound Channel Adapter without setting spring integration framework ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "setting spring integration"; the channel adapter is part of the Spring Integration project.

You can use the `JdbcTemplate` directly from the spring-jdbc project.

Comment: Yes I finally will use Spring JDBC StoredProcedures ... thank you